# Google Sheets get the active range on change

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to keep some text synced to the selected range on a spreadsheet.

Is there a way to trigger a callback whenever the selected range changes?

Comment: Did you look at the supported triggers in documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that when you say "selected range changes" that you mean that the selection changes and not the contents of the selected range.  I don't think there is a trigger that works for that for that.